# How to build a protractor without a protractor?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, geometric-construction

We all know how to use a protractor, it is taught in elementary school. However, I was wondering what type of knowledge is required to build one from scratch. 
For instance, was the understanding of $\pi$ and a compass first required before the first protractor, and if so how can I draw a full protractor on paper with just a compass, a ruler and some understanding of $\pi$?

I guess my point is, if we can draw a semi-circle on paper, then how can we fill up the degrees without the help of a protractor?

Comment: We live in an information age. Weren't there any Wiki How or YouTube results when you searched for this?

Comment: @JohnDouma I found how to make a partially made protractor, but not a full protractor with every single degree. I guess that level of precision requires some knowledge of geometry and intersections making that I just could not find.

Comment: I see what you mean. All of the sights seem to use a protractor or some kind of angle finder to lay out your protractor. You end up with a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: @JohnDouma that is precicely my point, I am hunting the creative process behind this engineering.

Comment: Hope the problem can be solved even without a ruler and a compass.

Comment: Well you have to start from somewhere.

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku 45, 90, 135 we'll get from just 2 folds of the semicircle, thinking about the rest

Comment: Check out https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ and https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/ These subsites might be what you need, because _"hunting the creative process"_ sounds like asking _about mathematics_, but not asking a _mathematical questions_.

Comment: $1$ degree angle is not compass/ruler constructible, but $3$ degrees is. Because a protractor is a measuring device (hence not exact by nature), there is no need not to interpolate a bit. Books on field theory often include a proof for the fact that a regular $9$-gon (i.e. a $40$ degree angle) is not constructible. Because $36$ degrees is constructible, it follows that $1=(40-36)/2^2$ cannot be constructed either.

Comment: I guess most monufacturing companies simply have a printed copy of a full protractor which they simply copy over and over again. But the creative mathematics seems to be hidden.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection). As @JyrkiLahtonen points out, you cannot trisect an arbitrary angle using straight-edge and compass but there are other methods that may be used. There are also approximations by bisection that are achievable.

Comment: Perhaps a clarification to JohnDouma 's comment may be needed: the approximations can be made arbitrarily close, that is, as precise as needed.

Comment: I just can't find a full project describing the entirety of its construction. What a beautiful piece of engineering!

Comment: You can calculate $\cos1^{\circ}$ from the Maclaurin series for cosine, that gives you the $x$-coordinate for one degree, once you have that, you've got the whhole protractor. The ancients didn't have Maclaurin series as such, but they were still able to work out tables of trig functions, might be worth looking up how they did that.

Comment: An actual protractor can only be manufactured to a certain level of precision anyway. The fact that you can't construct the one degree angle "exactly" doesn't really matter for that purpose.

Comment: You *can* construct a $\frac{63}{64}°$ angle, which is probably close enough to 1° for school math class purposes.

Comment: Why did you repost the question in [MathEducators.SE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/25592/282)? It is a bit rude to the answerers to do that without crosslinking the questions.

Answer (score 5):

I think there are two questions here: the practical question of what is actually done at a protractor factory, and the theoretical question of can you decompose a circle into $360$ equal pieces given only a straight-edge and compass.

I'll focus on the latter since the former is not really about mathematics. We know that $360 = 2^3\cdot3^2\cdot5$. Now, $72=2^3\cdot3^2$ degrees is a constructible angle, because a pentagon is constructive. Bisection is always possible, so that leaves angles that need to be trisected twice. This isn't possible with a straight-edge and compass (in general), BUT arbitrary trisection is possible with a ruler and compass (i.e. putting distances on your straight-edge is enough to over-come this hurdle). Wikipedia says this was already known to Archimedes.

Comment: At first I could not understand what you meant about "720 angles". If you want a degree symbol, try `$72^\circ$`. I also recommend only two `$` characters in any in-line equation, one at the very start of the left side of the equation and one at the very end of the right side.

Comment: Trisection isn't possible *in general*, but some particular angles can be trisected easily; for instance, it is very easy to trisect a right angle into three 30° angles. So, the fact that a 1° angle cannot be constructed requires more of a proof; the fact that 360 is a multiple of 3² isn't enough justification.

Comment: @Stef I did not attempt to prove that a $1^\circ$ angle is not constructible with a straight-edge and compass, I just suggested that one way to avoid worrying about it is to use a ruler and compass.

Answer (score 5):

For practical protractor production, take an image of a master protractor and print it on paper or plastic.

But I assume that what you *actually* want to know is: How do you construct a 1° angle?  So that you can mark that “master” protractor from scratch.

Start by constructing two shapes:

- An equilateral triangle.  As you know, it has 60° interior angles.  Bisect it to make a 30° angle.
- [A regular pentagon](https://www.wikihow.com/Construct-a-Regular-Pentagon).  It has 108° interior angles.  Bisect it twice to make a 27° angle.

Use these angles to construct a $30° - 27° = 3°$ angle.

Now, we just need to [trisect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_trisection) 3° to make 1°.  Unfortunately, it turns out that you can't do that with compass and straightedge.  But you do have a few options here:

- [Neusis construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neusis_construction), origami, or any known technique that can exactly trisect an arbitrary angle.
- Approximation.

  - Construct a 63° angle (you already have 60° and 3° available from the previous steps), and bisect it 6 times to make a $\frac{63}{64}°$ angle.
  - Or use the identity $\frac{1}{3} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{4^k}$.  Bisect your 3° angle twice to make a $\frac{3}{4}°$ angle, then repeatedly bisect it, adding every *second* bisected angle to your approximation until you're as close as you need to 1°.
- Just eyeball it.  What do you need to measure angles *for* anyway?  The trajectory of a manned rocket to Mars?  Positioning a scalpel for robot-assisted brain surgery?  Or some personal craft projects?  Assuming it's the latter, being off by a small fraction of a degree probably won't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was [cross-posted at MSE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/25592/29), I am reproducing (and slightly adapting) [the answer that I posted there](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/25597/29):

It is possible, with just straightedge and compass, to construct a regular 120-gon, and therefore it is possible to mark off every 3 degrees on a circle.

Can we get any farther? It depends on how much precision you require, and how much error you are willing to tolerate. In principle, it is not possible to trisect a $3^\circ$ angle using only a compass and straightedge.  However, the following *incorrect* trisection method produces angles that are very, very close to correct:

- Let $O$ be the center of a circle, and let $A, B$ be points on the circle such that arc $AB$ measures 3 degrees.
- Join $A$ to $B$ to create segment $\overline{AB}$.
- Trisect $\overline{AB}$ using a compass and straightedge, finding points $C, D \in \overline{AB}$ with $AC = CD = DB$.
- Draw rays $\overrightarrow{AC}$ and $\overrightarrow{AD}$.

The resulting angles $\angle AOC, \angle COD, \angle DOB$ are **not** exactly 1 degree each, but the difference between the actual measures and the desired measures are less than 1 part in 10,000.  Given the imprecision involved in using mechanical construction tools (how thick is the tip of your pencil? how smoothly can you draw an arc with a compass? how 'straight' is your straightedge?), and the inherent limits involved in reading or using a protractor (can you even measure a degree to less than 0.1 degree precision with a protractor anyway?), this would seem to be good enough for almost all conceivable purposes.